# Mostrar opciones de un Dropdownlist de una lista

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, lista, dropdownlist

En un proyecto de mvc en una vista deseo que aparezca en un dropdownlist todo la lista de los registros de un modelo (osea la clase) llamado tipografia en las opciones del Dropdownlist

> Cual es la estructura correcta para llamar los registros de tipografia al dropdownlist con la lista?

Comment: Yo diría que la forma correcta es cargar los datos en el controlador y pasarlos a la vista ya sea como modelo o por medio del ViewBag.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer uso de la clase `SelectList` que viene incluida en `System.Web.Mvc`, ejemplo:

```java
public ActionResult Create(){
    ViewBag.TipografiaId = new SelectList(
        db.Tipografias, "Id", "Nombre"
    );
    return View();
}
```

Aquí estás declarando una lista y pasándola desde el controlador a tu vista a través de un `ViewBag`, como te decía Luis en su comentario.

El primer parámetro espera una colección, en este caso todas las tipografías.

El segundo el valor que se va a cargar al seleccionar una tipografía, en este caso el `Id`

Y como tercer parámetro, el nombre que se va a mostrar en el `select`, yo supuse que una tipografía tiene un nombre, por eso puse `Nombre`.

La clase `SelectList` admite otros parámetros que deberías estudiarte ya que son de mucha ayuda, como cuarto parámetro puedes pasarle un objeto ya seleccionado para que se muestre, esto es de ayuda en el caso de los `Editar` en los que necesitas que ya venga seleccionada una tipografía.

Para consumirla en la vista solo llámala a través de `Helper`.

```
@Html.DropDownList(
    "TipografiaId ", null, new { @class = "form-control" }
)
```